# where to put apache common configuration file

Tags: java, apache-commons

i use apache common configuration library to extract my configuration list when my web started.

but its always thrown error Cannot locate configuration source.

where should i put my configuration file ?

here is web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Quartz</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>me.myclass.Init</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
</servlet>
```

and at my code :

```
public void init()
{
    XMLConfiguration xmlConfig;
    try {
        xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration("/WEB-INF/scheduler.xml");
        System.out.println(xmlConfig.getString("master"));
    } catch (org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are in a servlet, I recommend using the servlet context.  So long as your file is in WEB-INF it should be located with this code:

```
  ServletContext context = getServletContext();
  File schedulerFile = new File(context.getResource("/WEB-INF/scheduler.xml").getPath());
  xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration(schedulerFile);
```

From the JavaDocs:
getResource: Returns a URL to the resource that is mapped to a specified path. The path must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

Comment: Is there a location where configuration data that will be used by a Servlet could be placed so that it is specific to the environment on which it is running but not on the servlet's WAR file? (e.g. not in web.xml or the /WEB-INF/ folder, which ships with the Servlet classes). I have a Servlet that needs to run in multiple environments (e.g. connects to different servers for "dev", "test", and "production" but the WAR package itself shouldn't change from environment to environment.)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, file `scheduler.xml` should be in folder `WEB-INF` of your web application. If you put it in there, and it can't be read, check its permissions.

**Edit:** it's possible there's a classpath issue. For starters, try putting `scheduler.xml` in some well known place that's an absolute directory like `c:\Test\scheduler.xml` and then use

```
xmlConfig = new XMLConfiguration("c:/Test/scheduler.xml");
```

just to check if this way works.

Comment: i already put scheduler.xml at WEB-INF. and i use windows, i think there is should not any concern about permission. i don't have any clue how this can be happen.